# How to remove extra space in bottom of x axis label ie below zero mpandroidchart

Tags: android, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

Hi I used [MpAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library.  I mentioned label at bottom of the chart but it takes extra space to assign for label ie below 0 value. How to reduce or remove space at bottom of zero?

You can see screenshot below where there is a huge space between 0 and the label. How to remove that spacing?

[image]

```
  barChart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);
    XAxis xAxis = barChart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    YAxis leftAxis = barChart.getAxisLeft();
    leftAxis.setDrawAxisLine(true);
    leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(true);
    YAxis rightAxis = barChart.getAxisRight();
    rightAxis.setDrawAxisLine(true);
    rightAxis.setDrawGridLines(true);
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try to add:

```
leftAxis.setAxisMinValue(0f);
rightAxis.setAxisMinValue(0f);
```

**Hope, this answer will solve your problem.**

**Edit 1:**

For newer version, method has been changed to:

```
leftAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f);
rightAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f);
```

Comment: Also upvote, if it is the perfect and helpful answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm very happy when applying it.

Comment: its not work for me.can you please tell me anyother way is there?

Comment: @SNandhini Can you pls share what you have tried? Have you tried like this: `chart.getAxisRight().setAxisMinimum(0)`?

Comment: Not working, I want to remove bottom space and label altogether.

Comment: mChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);

Answer (score 1):

In version 3.0.2 method `setAxisMinValue` marked as @deprecated. 
New method is `xAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f);`